# Stuck on step regarding finding basis of a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am confused on something that I want clarification on.

$S = \langle \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\-3&0\\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}-4&6\\3&3\\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&2\\-1&1\\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4&6\\-9&3\\ \end{bmatrix}\rangle$

Which way am I supposed to organize the four matrices into one? Like this?

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & -3 & 0\\-4 & 6 & 3 & 3\\0 & 2 & -1 & 1\\4 & 6 & -9 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Or like this?

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & -4 & 0 & 4\\0 & 6 & 2 & 6\\-3 & 3 & -1 & -9\\0 & 3 & 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Neither. You are looking for all $2\times 2$ matrices that can be expressed as linear combinations of these four.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Aren't I supposed to be finding the rref of a large combination of the four matrices to find the basis though?

Comment: Yes. The first looks right to me if you think of the four coords of the "vector" as being in order $(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)$. Actually I was going to do the reduction on the four matrices just as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Okay, so you have four matrices, that can be rewritten as column vectors:

$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} \\ a_{12} \\ a_{21} \\ a_{22} \end{pmatrix}$

and to check for linear independence is equivalent to putting your second matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}\color{red}2 & \color{red}{-4} & 0 & 4\\\color{red}0 & \color{red}6 & 2 & 6\\\color{red}{-3} & \color{red}3 & -1 & -9\\\color{red}0 & \color{red}3 & 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\cong_{rref} \begin{bmatrix}\color{orange}1 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 4\\0 & \color{orange}1 & \frac{1}{3} & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

into RREF where the leading $\color{orange}{\text{ones}}$ correspond to the linearly independent $\color{red}{\text{column vectors}}$ of your matrix.

A basis $B=\{M_1,M_2,M_3,...,M_n\}$, where $n$ is at most $4$ (the matrices in $S$ are linearly independent), for $S$ is such that

- the matrices in $B$ are linearly independent.
- the matrices in $B$ span the subspace generated by $S$.

Let $B=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\-3& 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}-4&6\\3&3\end{bmatrix}\right\}$, then the above RREF states that

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}=\frac{2}{3}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\-3& 0\end{bmatrix}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}-4&6\\3&3\end{bmatrix}$

and

$\begin{bmatrix} 4& 6\\-9&3\end{bmatrix}=4\cdot \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\-3& 0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}-4&6\\3&3\end{bmatrix}$

and it turns out that every linear combination $aM_1+bM_2+cM_3+dM_4$ of the matrices in $S$ is really a linear combination of the first two matrices $gM_2+hM_2$.

You could also note that the first two matrices are linearly independent because they are not multiples of one another.

Thus $\text{span}(B)=\text{span}(S)$, and the matrices in $B$ are linearly independent. $B$ is a basis for $S$ and $\text{dimension}(S)=2$ where the dimension of $S$ is the $\#$ of vectors in a basis $B$ for $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $rank(M)=rank(M^{t})$ (the rank of the transpose of a matrix is the same of the matrix), you can choose what you want. You will find that the rank is 2, that means that the dimension of your subspace is 2. Then you have to choose 2 independent matrices $2\times 2$ in the subspace, for example: $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ -3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$,  $\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 6 \\ 3 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$ (the first two generators of the subspace are linear independent.)